# automated testing of OS installer (i.e. bare metal testing)

Tags: automated-testing, unix

Our software does bare metal recovery of servers, which essentially requires a boot disk to start the process and grab the original image off of the backup server.  While we can automate testing of a lot of the backup procedures, I have yet to find a way to test the restore procedures.

Our restore process runs in ncurses.  On a physical machine I can't think of any easy way to test this process, but what about in a VM?  Is there anything that could run on the host machine and simulate keyboard presses?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options-

[a USB keyboard emulator maybe ?](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/USB-Keyboard-Emulator_257478709.html)

Use an RS232 output to drive and simulate an RS232 keyboard?

ipmi remote console, if your platform supports it

Answer (score 0):

For a Mac host, there is Keyboard Maestro.  For Windows hosts, there's AutohotKey.  For Unix hosts, there are AutoKey, Xnee, or XDotool.